# Calculator - Allowing negative numbers in calculation

Tags: c#, calculator

For a practice assignment I need to create a calculator which can:

- Multiply
- Divide
- Add
- Subtract
- Handle decimals
- Handle negative numbers e.g. (2--3=5)

I have made everything work apart from the handling negative numbers and I dont really know how to do such a thing and thought you may be able to help. Here is my current solving code:

```
public decimal getResult(string equation)
{
   //parse a equation as a string and solve it
   List<string> numbers = input.Split(opSplit, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList<string>();
   List<string> operators = input.Split(numSplit, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList<string>();

   //remove any decimals from operators list
   for (int i = 0; i < operators.Count; i++)
   {
      if (operators[i] == ".")
      {
         operators.RemoveAt(i);
      }
   }

   //set total to first values in numbers then remove in from list
   decimal total = decimal.Parse(numbers[0]);
   numbers.Remove(total.ToString());

   int count = 0;

   foreach(string s in numbers) {
      decimal val = decimal.Parse(s);
      string current_operator = operators[count];
      MessageBox.Show(current_operator);
      switch (current_operator)
      {
         case "+":
            total += val;
         break;
         case "-":
            total -= val;
         break;
         case "x":
            total *= val;
         break;
         case "/":
            total /= val;
         break;
      }

      if (count != operators.Count-1)
      {
         count++;
      }
   }
   return total;
}
```

My equations are inputed in this format.

- 1+2-3*4/5

Comment: Can you clarify the issue?

Comment: Do you need to follow order of operations? (1+2*3=7 or 1+2*3=9?)

Comment: Are you talking about a scenario where you need to input a negative number and add it to another?  1+2+-3*4/5?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel, I think he's asking how to tell if -3 means negative 3 or if it means subtract 3.  But that's a guess...

Comment: In your code example you have a string variable "equation", and then you have "input" which kinda looks like a string variable too. I guess that should be the same variable, or am i mistaken?

Comment: I want to be able to have an equation such as 3--5 so in the end it will be 3 plus -5. Equation and input are the same variable.

Comment: Do i understand your code correct in that you do not allow numbers with a decimal point?

Comment: @Duncan, if your equations are of the form •1+2-3*4/5 then why are you switching on 'x'?

Answer (score 3):

First of all: right now you're not taking into account the order of operations, which is a very bad idea.

I assume you want to do something like this: `-3 + -5`, correct?

Here are a few assumptions that you can make:

- Do not set the initial value equal to the first value

Set `total = 0` instead. That way, if you start with `-5`, you have the equation `0 - 5` which is already correct and there's no hassle with the initial value.

- Simplify the mathematical operations

`-3 + -5` is the same as `0 - 3 - 5`. Take advantage of this: parse your operators and check if you have two operators following eachother. If you have this: simplify the operation and you're good to go.

For good measure:

```
+-------------+
| op | op | = |
+-------------+
| +  | +  | + |
| +  | -  | - |
| -  | +  | - |
| -  | -  | + |
+-------------+
```

Comment: How about simplification for * and /?

Comment: There is no simplification for `*` and `/` because these aren't indicators for positivity or negativity. What would you simplify about it?

Comment: Well, if you have to treat the negativity sign "-" explicitly for * and / anyhow, then nothing speaks against treating it always explicitely. Which would turn your simplification suggestion actually into increased code complexity without much of a benefit.

Comment: @elgonzo: you are correct, that is indeed a good remark. I don't have an answer to it immediatly because frankly there are so many side remarks that would basically require a very extensive code if you want to parse everything correctly. I'll leave this up though since it suffices for simple operations